# Indy sending file and close open handle(s)

Tags: delphi-7, indy, delphi, indy-9

I use this code to send a file to a client.

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
 hFile    : THandle;
 FileBuff : array [0..1023] of byte;
 dwRead   : DWORD;
 Recieved : String;
begin
 Recieved := Athread.Connection.ReadLn;
 if Recieved = 'FILE' then begin
   Memo1.Lines.Add('Sending File...');
   hFile := CreateFileW('FILE.bin',
   GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
   if hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then exit;
   SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
   while true do begin
     ReadFile(hFile, FileBuff[0], 1024, dwRead, nil);
     if dwRead <= 0 then break;
     Athread.Connection.WriteBuffer(FileBuff[0], dwRead);
   end;
   CloseHandle (hFile);
   Athread.Connection.Disconnect;
 end;
end;
```

This works like a charm but if the client disconnects while the file is sending, Indy terminates the Execute Thread immediately so the filehandle is still open! Is there a way to close the filehandle after the client disconnects?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you tried using `try..finally..end`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has three problems in it:

1) accessing the TMemo directly is not thread-safe, so it can cause deadlocks and/or crashed.  UI access must be done in the context of the main thread only.  You can use Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class to safely access the UI from server events.

2) like RRUZ mentioned, you are not protecting the file handle from exceptions.  If an exception is raised, like when a client disconnects, you are not closing the file handle.

3) you are opening the file using a relative path.  Always use absolute paths to ensure the correct file is used.

Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread); 
var 
 hFile    : THandle; 
 FileBuff : array [0..1023] of byte; 
 dwRead   : DWORD; 
 Recieved : String; 
begin 
  Recieved := Athread.Connection.ReadLn; 
  if Recieved = 'FILE' then begin 
    // I'll leave this as an exercise for you to figure out...
    //Memo1.Lines.Add('Sending File...'); 

    hFile := CreateFile('C:\Path\FILE.bin', GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0); 
    if hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      repeat 
        if not ReadFile(hFile, FileBuff[0], SizeOf(FileBuff), dwRead, nil) then RaiseLastOSError;
        if dwRead = 0 then Break; 
        AThread.Connection.WriteBuffer(FileBuff[0], dwRead);
      until False;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hFile); 
    end;
    AThread.Connection.Disconnect; 
  end; 
end;
```

Alternatively, you can pass the filename to Indy and let it manage the file for you:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread); 
var 
 Recieved : String; 
begin 
  Recieved := Athread.Connection.ReadLn; 
  if Recieved = 'FILE' then begin 
    // I'll leave this as an exercise for you to figure out...
    //Memo1.Lines.Add('Sending File...'); 

    AThread.Connection.WriteFile('C:\Path\FILE.bin', True); 
    AThread.Connection.Disconnect; 
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: looks good! thank you very much. I just didnt know that try except would actually get called in that situation.